# Xcode eligible Devices

Tags: ios, xcode, profile

I have just started developing games for iOS devices. Recently i got a new macbook, and when to run an app from Xcode my devices are listed as : "ineligible devices". It seems like Xcode cannot see that I am a developer, I have of course signed in as my developer account under preferences. When I did this the first time it said "private key missing", then i exported my developer profile from my last mac, and now it says valid, but it has not solved my problem.

Helt would be really appreciated, if I should specify something please tell me:)

Thanks
Anders

Answer (score 0):

Go Xcode cmd+, to preferences than Accounts under your AppleID double click Team and than click left down corner button.

Note that you have to be logged in..[image]

Comment: I did not read it all please ignore/ but try that! I will give you some error message...

Comment: Hehe thanks for a fast reply - but i am not quite sure what you mean, could you write it again?

Comment: Try clicking the kinda arrow button, then Done and try to build your project

Answer (score 0):

Please be sure of two things:

1) your device is in your Provision Profile

2) your app's target ios version is less than or equal to your device's ios version.

Hope these help.

Comment: I do not think so, but how do i see which devices are in my provisioning profile?

Comment: Also it is kinda strange but also it does not give me an option to choose a simulator, there is just one option: "iOS device" and under "Eligible devices" I see my iPhone or iPad

Comment: You can see your provisioning profile from developer portal. It is really strange because you must be able to select a simulator even without a developer account. I didn't understand why you aren't able to select a simulator

Answer (score 0):

Change your deployment target.

[image]